# Map type to string

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

If I have a type like this

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // Other properties that are not mapped...
}
```

in which there is only one mapped property which is of type string, how do I map all references to SomeType to a simple text column (the value of SomeType.Text) and thus avoid generating a SomeType table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SomeType` is not defined as entity (i.e. there is no `DbSet<SomeType>` in your context), then it is a [Complex Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147.aspx) and it's value will be stored in same table as entity which uses your complex type. So, if you have entity `Customer` like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public SomeType Foo { get; set; }
    // other members
}
```

Then in `Customers` table you will have column `Foo_Text`. Separate table for `SomeType` will not be created. The only restriction with complex types is that you can't have `null` value for them.

---

Also you can specify mappings for your complex type if default column name `EntityPropertyName_ComplexTypePropertyName` does not suits your needs:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<SomeType>()
            .Property(st => st.Text).HasColumnName("Text");
```

Comment: Sometimes I forget basic things :( Just a litte add-on: I think, `SomeType` also must not have a property that EF recognizes as key by convention (`Id` or `SomeTypeId`), otherwise it'll assume it's an entity, even without a `DbSet`. I believe that's the work of a `ComplexTypeDiscoveryConvention`.

Comment: @Slauma thanks, and very good notice about `Id` property. Didn't know that

Comment: What will happen with a mapped property of type IList<SomeType>?

Comment: @HappyNomad you can't store list of values in column. If you have several items related to record, then you should set relation via foreign keys.